# How to write Firebase Cloud Messaging function to send push notification

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, dart, flutter

I'm trying to send push notifications from admin interface to users via FCM,
I got that part where users subscribe to admins topic.

It's working when I send the notification from Firebase console.
Admins can upload data to Firebases realtime database,which includes the text of the notification, and the topic(tell me if something is missing).

How to write the Firebase **function** that triggers when a notification is uploaded to realtime DB,and sends a notification to those users who are subscribes to that topic?
I would be very glad if someone would share an example with me,because I'm not familiar with node.js...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you needed is database trigger as outlined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). You can write a function like:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database  
            .ref('/notification/{topicId}/messages/{messageId}')
            .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {


    const topicId  = context.params.topicId;
    const messageId = context.params.messageId;
    const summaryLabel = topicId +"-"messageId; 
    const receivedOn = Date.now();

    const payload = {

        data: {
            topicId: topicId,
            messageId: messageId,
            time: receivedOn
        },

        notification: {
            title: "Notification Title",
            body: summaryLabel,
            icon: '/img/blue_map_icon.png',
            click_action: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com`,
            sound: "default"
        }
    };

    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 2
    }; 

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topicId, payload, options);


});
```

Comment: How should my DB structure look like?

Comment: It depends up on your business logic. You may have such attributes like: `channelId`, `notificationTitle`, `notificationBody`,  `createdBy`, `createdTimestamp`, `priority`, `timeToLive`, `iconUrl`...

Comment: Tested it,its working! Thanks a lot!